# How can I create a shorter version of my parallax?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Basically, I have created a parallax effect with 6 images with media queries for desktop and mobile. The images display fine in desktop mode. However, once I shrink my screen to mobile mode, some of the images just cut off and are not responsive. Because of this, I would like my parallax to only show 4 images on mobile view and the regular 6 images on desktop view. I have tried rearranging my code with my media queries to get this, but I can't seem to figure out a way. How can I do this so only the "viewable" images are only shown on mobile view? Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

```css
section.module h2 {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
section.module p {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
section.module.content {
    padding: 40px 0;
    background-color: #AFC9F1;
}
section.module.parallax {
    height: 800px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
section.module.parallax h1 {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 600px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
section.module.parallax-0 {
    background-image: url("https://mms.businesswire.com/media/20170310005534/en/574694/5/NIO_EVE_04_Fr34.jpg");
    height: 100vh;
    opacity: 0.65;
}
section.module.parallax-1 {
    background-image: url("https://mms.businesswire.com/media/20170310005534/en/574694/5/NIO_EVE_04_Fr34.jpg");
}
section.module.parallax-2 {
    background-image: url("https://autodesignmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/2017031301_nio_eve.jpg");
}
section.module.parallax-3 {
    background-image: url("https://www.nio.com/prod/s3fs-public/styles/tile_double_square_desktop_1x/public/2018-09/zip-eve-gallery-5.jpg?Agd8SYcynlrs7LqQu6N.GbrzxLw8vYJF&itok=hGg1N1lm");
}
section.module.parallax-4 {
    background-image: url("https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/bP1-Ysv4wJcYCMLrAoJv-T03Oto=/0x0:1920x1080/1400x1050/filters:focal(807x387:1113x693):format(jpeg)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/53656791/EVE_005_Overhead.0.jpg");
}
section.module.parallax-5 {
    background-image: url("https://cimg1.ibsrv.net/ibimg/hgm/1920x1080-1/100/595/nio-eve-concept-2017-sxsw_100595869.jpg");
}
/* Parallax Mobile */
@media (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 899px) {
    section.module.parallax-0 {
        background-image: url("https://miro.medium.com/max/3840/1*LT87ktpOB50UhsrRJYjI5A.jpeg");
    }
    section.module.parallax-1 {
        background-image: url("https://miro.medium.com/max/3840/1*LT87ktpOB50UhsrRJYjI5A.jpeg");
    }
    section.module.parallax-2 {
        background-image: url("https://autodesignmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/2017031301_nio_eve.jpg");
    }
    section.module.parallax-3 {
        background-image: url("https://www.nio.com/prod/s3fs-public/styles/tile_double_square_desktop_1x/public/2018-09/zip-eve-gallery-5.jpg?Agd8SYcynlrs7LqQu6N.GbrzxLw8vYJF&itok=hGg1N1lm");
    }
    section.module.parallax-4 {
        background-image: url("https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/bP1-Ysv4wJcYCMLrAoJv-T03Oto=/0x0:1920x1080/1400x1050/filters:focal(807x387:1113x693):format(jpeg)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/53656791/EVE_005_Overhead.0.jpg");
    }
    section.module.parallax-5 {
        background-image: url("https://cimg1.ibsrv.net/ibimg/hgm/1920x1080-1/100/595/nio-eve-concept-2017-sxsw_100595869.jpg");
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Parallax</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="module parallax parallax-0">
        <div class="container text-center"></div>
    </section>
  <section class="module parallax parallax-1">
        <div class="container text-center"></div>
    </section>
  <section class="module parallax parallax-2">
        <div class="container text-center"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="module parallax parallax-3">
        <div class="container text-center"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="module parallax parallax-4">
        <div class="container text-center"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="module parallax parallax-5">
        <div class="container text-center"></div>
    </section>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play with `background-size:contain` on your `section.module.parallax` class for the mobile view. And for displaying images, you can put `display: none` on images you don't want to show on mobile.

If I understood you well.